# Why does fock space representation need to assume the particles do not interact?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I do not understand where this assumption is needed. Can you explain to me why this is needed?
Also, in this case, does this mean that fock space representation is only valid for free particles?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is **used** to construct Fock space. The construction does not work if interaction terms are included. A theory with interactions could have bound states that are not obviously describable in the free particle Fock space. It needs to be proved that the Hilbert space representation of the interacting theory is equivalent to the free particle Fock space (see [Haag's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=haag+theorem)).

Comment: May you explain why the bound states are not obviously describable by the Fock space?